# Model objects to be grouped by date field in another model

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I had two models, one called reviews and the other called answers, as you can see from its names, one review has many answers ( exactly 7) a classic one to many relationships.

I'm able to do all the common stuff with this straight forward relationship, filtering, prefech_related, even prefetching only some answers with a condition.

Now, I want to do a group by review date with the answers objects in that day, as you can see, my problem is how I can do that because I will group many objects with just one field, the normal aggregate in Django are just sum and count, but I want the objects

I was searching for a while about this and I can't see a solution where this can be done with orm to produce a queryset then serialize it or in SQL

Thank you

**Edit**:

To summarize my problem in simple words, I want to get all the objects of the group by field, for ex: if the date 2019-12-12 had 10 answers then rather than the normal annotations which do count or sum I want to get these 10 objects

Thank you again

**Edit 2**:

Here is my review model

```
class Review(model.Model):
    #other fields omitted
    submitted_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-submitted_at',)
```

and my answer model

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(
        Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

sample of the normal output

```
  [
     {
      "submitted_at": "2019-10-08T16:13:36.356275+02:00",
      "answers": [
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 11
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "submitted_at": "2019-10-08T16:13:36.234108+02:00",
      "answers": [
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 5
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 11
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "submitted_at": "2019-10-08T16:13:36.168304+02:00",
      "answers": [
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 8
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 8
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 10
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
```

What I'm aiming for after grouping by submitted_at with only the date portion is something like this

```
  [
   {
      "submitted_at": "2019-10-08",
      "answers": [
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 11
        },
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 5
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 4
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 7
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 11
        },
        {
          "question": 1,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 2,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 3,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 4,
          "choice": 1
        },
        {
          "question": 5,
          "choice": 8
        },
        {
          "question": 6,
          "choice": 8
        },
        {
          "question": 7,
          "choice": 10
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Of course, it can be much better if I can subgroup by question but I think it may be hard so let's try to solve the big one first

Comment: Add some data and sample output always for faster answers

Comment: @Fact I would gladly add these from the beginning if it helps, but I doubt. I added and abstracted my problem in one phrase if this can help, check it

Comment: For this depending on the database you have to use analytical function like row_number, sum(column) Over(), avg(col) Over(), lead, lag, count(col) over(). Again if you can produce some data and expected ouput that will be helpful to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: @Fact thanks for your help, I will try to provide these

Comment: @Fact snippets added

Comment: Thanks this makes it clearer. I can help you with sqls only and my idea would be to create the Review and Answer model as a database table. Once in the database you convert the datetimestamp to date datatype (in a view or in the select statement) and join the two table. It's a staright fowrawd join of two tables in database.

Comment: @Fact my problem is exactly on what condition should I join between the two tables because it's a converted date, not the normal review_id, also one date would have many other answers so how SQL should handle that since it's not JSON if you get what I mean

Comment: Since you haven't provided the schema, I can guess that date and reviewId would be join columns, and its pretty common in sql to have 1-N relationship. Just need the relation key to join the tables.Hope this helps

Comment: @Fact so if I get you right I do group by date and for each date I get it's review ids and then use these id's to join with the other answers table, right? if so can you point to an exmple or a resource that talk about this

Comment: That would be the approach, I just added an answer to help you understand what I meant to say, this may not be exactly what you want but would be my best guess given the lack of clarity on the schema and actual data of the t tables.

Answer (score 1):

You rightly guessed in your comment - group by datetimestamp coverted to date and review Id.
The code is run in postgres 12. Core of the logic remains the same in any databases

```
 With Reviews as 
 (
 Select '2019-10-08 12:13:36'::timestamp submitted_at, 100 reviewid Union all
 Select '2019-10-08 13:13:36'::timestamp, 100 Union all
 Select '2019-10-08 14:13:36'::timestamp,100
 ) 
 ,reviews_grouped_by_date as
  (
   Select Date_trunc('day',submitted_at) submitted_at , reviewid from Reviews
   group by date_trunc('day',submitted_at),reviewId
 )
,answers as
 (
 Select 1 question , 4 choice, 100 reviewId,'2019-10-08'::date dateans union all
 Select 2,4 ,100,'2019-10-08'::date union all
 Select 3,4 ,100,'2018-10-08'::date union all
 Select 1,4 ,200,'2019-10-08'::date
 )
Select answers.dateans, answers.question, answers.choice,answers.reviewid
From reviews_grouped_by_date 
JOIN answers ON reviews_grouped_by_date.reviewid=answers.reviewId
        AND reviews_grouped_by_date.submitted_at=answers.dateans
```

Comment: Really thanks for your helpful answer, I think I got some inspiration to do it  using ORM or even if I didn't succeed I know which road to take using SQL

Answer (score 0):

Grouping based on field can be done by following way.

```
Answer.objects.values("review__submitted_at", "question__your_field_name", choice__your_field_name).annotate(Count("question__your_field_name")).order_by("question__your_field_name")
```

Comment: are you sure about that? because this counts question for each row and it will always result in 1, it doesn't do a group by and even if you mean aggregators functions like sum and count it's not what I'm looking for or it's my problem, please read my question again carefully

Comment: I have already tried before writing my comment and it' doesn't work

Comment: answers.values("review__submitted_at", "question_id", 'choice_id').annotate(Count("question_id")).order_by("question_id")

Comment: {
      "review__submitted_at": "2019-01-08T16:00:55Z",
      "question_id": 1,
      "choice_id": 5,
      "question_id__count": 1
    }

Comment: add more instances and see the out put

Comment: this is one object out of the 2241 objects I had in my table and the query resulted

Comment: if you want group by based on date, you have to remove the question_id and choice_id

Comment: I want to group by date and get the answer objects for each grouped date, count or sum is not what I'm looking for

Comment: remove question_id and choice_id field, and use field names, id field will give individual instance only

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django QuerySet API to filter the Answer by the date:

```
def get_answer_by_date(date):
    answers_by_date = Answer.objects.filter(review__submitted_at__date=date)

   return {"submitted_at":date, "answers":answers_by_date.values("question", "choice")}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#date

Comment: that's simple for sure but I will have to put it in a loop to do it for all dates, I'm looking to do it with db layer either by orm or sql because for large dataset it will take time